# Android app array multiple objects

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make an app where every user will have 15 different types of units and every single of those units will have their unique level.

I have created class Player for every single player. How i should add units to players class as I understand units should be created as different class?

Comment: Can all those classes implement a common interface ? or Can all of them inherit from a single class ?

Comment: Could you please add some more details, what you have tried, your ideas,  code, etc.?

Comment: Well one of ideas is to create 30 variables(15 units 2 variables each), but that as I understand is bad programming practice. So I think i should create other class. So then i could have 15 variables (one variable for unit). Is there way to make it even smaller?